# Convert a file encoding using R? (ANSI to UTF-8)

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I wish to convert an HTML file encoded in ANSI to UTF-8, using R.

Is there a tool, or a combination of tools, that can make this work?

Thanks.

**Edit**: o.k, I've narrowed my problem to another one.  It is re-posted here:  [Using "cat" to write non-English characters into a .html file (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483742/using-cat-to-write-non-english-characters-into-a-html-file-in-r)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use iconv:

```
writeLines(iconv(readLines("tmp.html"), from = "ANSI_X3.4-1986", to = "UTF8"), "tmp2.html")
```

tmp2.html should be utf-8.

---

**Edit by Henrik in June 2015:**
A working solution for Windows distilled from the comments is as follows:

```
writeLines(iconv(readLines("tmp.html"), from = "ANSI_X3.4-1986", to = "UTF8"), 
           file("tmp2.html", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

**Update 2021**: And if ANSI is the current locale, the following works as well (i.e., uses the local encoding as `from` source):

```
writeLines(iconv(readLines("tmp.html"), from = "", to = "UTF8"), 
           file("tmp2.html", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Comment: But what with html headers? Shouldn't be changed either?

Comment: Thanks Kohske, but this doesn't work for me.  It will convert the text in the file, but in some weird way, not the file itself.  When I used notepad++ to look at the encoding, it is still ANSI, and only through notepad++ can I change it to UTF8 (your code won't do it).  Any suggestions? :)

Comment: How about changing `from = "CP1252"` ?

Comment: Kohske - this is indeed the correct encoding to use.  But when I read the file into R, it interprets the text correctly.  I'll try to update my question to better explain...

Comment: @TalGalili You need to define `file` connection with proper encoding (see `?file`). Something like `f<-file("tmp2.html", encoding="UTF-8")` and then `writeLines(....., f)`.

Comment: Thanks Marek.  This looks to be in the right direction, but no success yet.  Please continue this on the new thread I started (which has an updated question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483742/using-cat-to-write-non-english-characters-into-a-html-file-in-r

Comment: What does your test html file contain?  From `?Encoding`: "ASCII strings will never be marked with a declared encoding, since their representation is the same in all supported encodings."  Also try `useBytes = TRUE` in the call to `writeLines`.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the solutions proposed above, especially with the TAB character. This alternative never disappointed me. Unfortunately it only works on UNIX-like systems.

```
system('iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 < tmp.html > tmp2.html')
```