# Using "cat" to write non-English characters into a .html file (in R)

Tags: html, r, utf-8, hebrew, cat

Here is the code showing the problem:

```
myPath = getwd()
cat("abcd", append = T, file =paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\")) # This is fine
cat("<BR/><BR/><BR/>", append = T, file =paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\")) # This is fine
cat("שלום", append = F, file =paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\")) # This text gets garbled when the html is opened using google chrome on windows 7.
cat("שלום", append = F, file =paste(myPath,"temp1.txt", sep = "\\")) # but if I open this file in a text editor - the text looks fine

# The text in the HTML folder would look as if I where to run this in R:
(x <- iconv("שלום", from = "CP1252", to = "UTF8") )
# But if I where to try and put it into the file, it wouldn't put anything in:
cat(x, append = T, file =paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\")) # empty
```

**Edit:**
I've also tried using the following encoding (without success)

```
ff <-file(paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\"), encoding="CP1252")
cat("שלום", append = F, file =ff)
ff<-file(paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\"), encoding="utf-8")
cat("שלום", append = F, file =ff)
ff<-file(paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\"), encoding="ANSI_X3.4-1986")
cat("שלום", append = F, file =ff)
ff<-file(paste(myPath,"temp1.html", sep = "\\"), encoding="iso8859-8")
cat("שלום", append = F, file =ff)
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you need some sleep... =)
`Sys.sleep(sample(3600 * .5:8.5, 1))`

Comment: Take a look at this question [about saving csv with UTF-8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7402307/168747).

Comment: Hi Marek, when I try using it I get the text turning into "\xf9\xec\xe5\xed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit redundant. Is `temp1.txt` on line 5 a typo (`.html`)? Anyway, perhaps you should set *charset* within `<meta>` tag.

Take this as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<%
cat("abcd")
cat("<BR/><BR/><BR/>")
cat("שלום")
cat("שלום")
(x <- iconv("שלום", from = "CP1252", to = "UTF8") )
cat(x)
-%>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a `brew` code, so if you go ahead and `brew` it, you'll get correct response. Long story short, the keyword was *charset*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn’t with R (R is correctly producing UTF-8 encoded output) … it’s just that your web browser assumes the wrong encoding in the absence of an explicitly specified encoding. Just use the following snippet (from inside R) instead:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        שלום
    </body>
</html>
```

This specifies a correct encoding (UTF-8), and hence causes the browser to thread the following text correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
cat("abcd", file = (con <- file("temp1.html", "w", encoding="UTF-8"))); close(con)
```

Comment: Thanks gd047, but it doesn't work.  It leaves me with this: ×©×œ×•×.  Instead of שלום