# Writing data isn't preserving encoding

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

I have a string like the following:

```
str <- "ていただけるなら"
Encoding(str) #returns "UTF-8"
```

I write it to disk:

```
write.table(str, file="chartest", quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F)
```

Now I look at the file in Notepadd++, which is set to UTF-8 without BOM encoding, and I get this:

```
<U+3066><U+3044><U+305F><U+3060><U+3051><U+308B><U+306A><U+3089>
```

What is going wrong in this process?  I would like the written text file to display the string as it appears in R.

This is on Windows 7, R version 2.15

Comment: Try this: `writeLines(str, "chartest2.txt", useBytes=TRUE)`

Answer (score 16):

This is an annoying "feature" of R in Windows. The only solution that I have found so far is to temporarily and programatically switch your locale to the appropriate one required to decode the script of the text in question. So, in the above case you would use the Japanese locale.

```
## This won't work on Windows
str <- "ていただけるなら"
Encoding(str) #returns "UTF-8"
write.table(str, file="c:/chartest.txt", quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F)
## The following should work on Windows - first grab and save your existing locale
print(Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE"))
original_ctype <- Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE")
## Switch to the appropriate local for the script
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","japanese")
## Now you can write your text out and have it look as you would expect
write.table(str, "c:/chartest2.txt", quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, 
            row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
## ...and don't forget to switch back
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", original_ctype)
```

The above produces the two files you can see in this screenshot. The first file shows the Unicode code points, which is not what you want, while the second shows the glyphs you would normally expect.

[image: Japanese text]

So far nobody has been able to explain to me why this happens in R. It is not an unavoidable feature of Windows because Perl, as I mention in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069908/r-extracting-clean-utf-8-text-from-a-web-page-scraped-with-rcurl) post, gets round the issue somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Japanese was just an example, I'd like something that works for all language types.  Doesn't sound that promising though.

Comment: @qua - Yes, I thought it might be a random example given that you broke the Japanese string at a rather odd place. Unfortunately at this point I don't think a better solution exists for R, but please do create your own answer to this question if you find one! I agree that if you do not know the script beforehand you might struggle with my approach because (amongst other problems) it would require you to guess at the script being used and there simply is no surefire way of establishing the encoding type.

Comment: @SlowLearner Is there a way to list all the valid values for LC_CTYPE?

Comment: I do not know. I had a very specific usage aim so when I found what I was looking for I stopped searching.

Comment: @SlowLearner Man, you are the best !!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using argument `fileEncoding` ?

```
write.table(str, file="chartest", quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F, fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Trying that doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: OK so at the time i had tried on my work computer (on Mac OSX) and it worked but since then I tried on my home computer (Windows 7) and it didn't indeed.