# Invalid multibyte string in read.csv

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to import a csv that is in Japanese. This code:

```
url <- 'http://www.mof.go.jp/international_policy/reference/itn_transactions_in_securities/week.csv'
x <- read.csv(url, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

returns the following error:

```
Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, na.strings = character(0L)) : 
invalid multibyte string at '<91>ΊO<8b>y<82>ёΓ<e0><8f>،<94><94><84><94><83><8c>_<96>̏@(<8f>T<8e><9f><81>E<8e>w<92><e8><95>@<8a>փx<81>[<83>X<81>j'
```

I tried changing the encoding (`Encoding(url) <- 'UTF-8'` and also to latin1) and tried removing the read.csv parameters, but received the same "invalid multibyte string" message in each case. Is there a different encoding that should be used, or is there some other problem?

Comment: Have you tried to set the argument `encoding="UTF-8"` to `read.csv()`?

Comment: Yes, with the same result.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`Encoding` sets the encoding of a character string.  It doesn't set the encoding of the file represented by the character string, which is what you want.

This worked for me, after trying `"UTF-8"`:

```
x <- read.csv(url, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fileEncoding="latin1")
```

And you may want to skip the first 16 lines, and read in the headers separately.  Either way, there's still quite a bit of cleaning up to do.

```
x <- read.csv(url, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
  fileEncoding="latin1", skip=16)
# get started with the clean-up
x[,1] <- gsub("\u0081|`", "", x[,1])    # get rid of odd characters
x[,-1] <- as.data.frame(lapply(x[,-1],  # convert to numbers
  function(d) type.convert(gsub(d, pattern=",", replace=""))))
```

Comment: Thanks. From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069908/r-extracting-clean-utf-8-text-from-a-web-page-scraped-with-rcurl) I tried setting the local to japanese with `Sys.setlocale` but that didn't work either ("OS reports request to set locale to "japanese" cannot be honored").

Comment: Yes, read.csv("foobar.csv", fileEncoding = "latin1") worked for me. I had an Excel file and saved as CSV, then had to set the fileEncoding to "latin1" to read that CSV in R.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich, what if my code looks like this? `file.list <- list.files(pattern = '*.txt')
file.list <- file.list[order(nchar(file.list), file.list)]
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_file)
df_virgi <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df.list)`  where shall I place **fileEncoding = "latin1"? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18):

You may have encountered this issue because of the incompatibility of system locale 
try setting the system locale with this code `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")`

Answer (score 12):

The readr package from the tidyverse universe might help.

You can set the encoding via the local argument of the `read_csv()` function by using the `local()` function and its encoding argument:

```
read_csv(file = "http://www.mof.go.jp/international_policy/reference/itn_transactions_in_securities/week.csv",
         skip = 14,
         local = locale(encoding = "latin1"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I found for this issue without losing any data/special character (for example when using `fileEncoding="latin1"` characters like the Euro sign € will be lost) is to open the file first in a text editor like Sublime Text, and to "Save with encoding - UTF-8".

Then R can import the file with no issue and no character loss.

Answer (score 0):

For those using `Rattle` with this issue Here is how I solved it:

1. First make sure to quit rattle so your at the R command prompt
2. `> library (rattle)` (if not done so already)
3. `> crv$csv.encoding="latin1"`
4. `> rattle()`
5. You should now be able to carry on. ie, *import your csv > Execute > Model > Execute* etc.

That worked for me, hopefully that helps a weary traveller

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with scientific articles and found a good solution here:
http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html

By using the following line of code:

```
tm_map(yourCorpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte")))
```

you convert the multibyte strings into hex code.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you are trying to import into R that was originally an Excel file. Make sure you open the original file and Save as a csv and that fixed this error for me when importing into R.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and tried all the above to no avail. The issue vanished when I upgraded from R 3.4.0 to 3.4.3, so if your R version is not up to date, update it!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error (`invalid multibyte string 1`) recently, but my problem was a bit different:

We had forgotten to save a csv.gz file with an extension, and tried to use `read_csv()` to read it. Adding the extension solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Reproduce the read.csv error on multi-byte char repeatedly:

R's `read.csv()` will puke on all multi-byte characters if it is expecting a number.

**I'm using Version:** `R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)`

Put this data in file named: `/tmp/foo.csv`

```
#year,someval 
2022,0.1389 
2021,0.0000°
2020,0.2857
```

If you look close you can see the `0.0000` value on line 2 has a 'degree' symbol on it.

**Load it this way using read.csv:**

```
> read.csv('/tmp/foo.csv')

Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<b0>0'
Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> type.convert -> type.convert.default
Execution halted
```

What does `cat` have to say about that guff:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.csv 
#year,someval
2022,0.1389
2021,0.0000�
2020,0.2857
```

We do not tolerate that "Degrees" symbol.  Changing the encoding does nothing to help.  You could try telling read.csv to interpret everything as a string, but now you've got string to number conversion issues downstream.

**What does read.csv2 have to say?:**

```
> read.csv2('/tmp/foo.csv')
  X.year.someval
1 2022,0.1389
2 2021,0.000\xb0
3 2020,0.2857
```

https://www.codetable.net/hex/b0

Answer (score 0):

Did you use copy-paste to create CSV-file? I had the same error and successfully tried the most popular solution from this thread (**fileEncoding="latin1"**). After I re-saved the data frame into a CSV-file, I found that some cells had extra space after the cell value (encoded as A-tilde). I removed these spaces in the original file and was able to read it without **fileEncoding="latin1"** and without any error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34081960)

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with DBI connection reading a sql file with `read_lines`; but seems the file  has nothing to do with.
Refreshing my sql connection (re-connect) solves the issue.

I have not idea that strange behavior.

```
Sys.info()
       sysname        release        version             machine 
     "Windows"       "10 x64"  "build 19044"             "x86-64"
```