# Invalid Input causes read.csv to cut off data

Tags: r

I have been trying to read a csv file into R, but it keeps cutting off. I think it might be due to the file encoding, but I'm not sure.

Here is the code I ran:

```
read.csv('crunchbase_companies_2.csv', fileEncoding="UTF-8", quote="")
```

I then get a warning message: `In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,: invalid input found on input connection`.

R reads the data, but only up to when it hits a special character and then stops. So I only end up with partial data in R. I pasted the data I get here: http://pastebin.com/EQLnXz2W. Note though it cuts off when it hits things like 'Ì'. So those characters are not in the sample data.

I have also checked the encoding in the terminal using `file`. It returns `Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with CR line terminators`.

What do I need to do to read the entire dataset?

Answer (score 11):

So while I don't quite know why, what ended up working is changing `fileEncoding` to `latin1` when calling the read.csv function.

This was mentioned in a different answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv?rq=1). Somehow that's one thing I hadn't tried...

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar problem today and spent hours on it. 
I try to change encoding/fileEncoding, setlocal, and a couple of other things found here. But none of them work for me.

Eventually I found a non-English post (those people probably have more experience with this) and this trick：change the open model from "r" to "rb".

In my case, I use readLines, so it's

```
fileIn=file("userinfo.csv",open="rb",encoding="UTF-8")
lines = readLines(fileIn, n = rowPerRead, warn = FALSE)
```

I don't fully understand why, my guess is that the Unicode character is in Byte, so if it's not read by Byte, that big guy will just block the scan.

Comment: That worked for me as well, with the latin1 encoding in a latin1 locale (Windows) with the occasional misencoded character in the input file. I didn't need it to read more or less the same latin1 files in a utf-8 system (Linux), but didn't test with so many files there. Can only speculate why it works.

Answer (score 4):

After hours struggling with a csv like this, experimenting with arguments to `read.csv` like `fileEncoding` and `quote` I finally used `read_csv` in the `readr` package - simply with the default arguments - and it loaded everything perfectly straight away!

An unimaginative answer but worth trying before you attempt to reverse engineer the whole file yourself...

Comment: omg this is important!  What a lot of work otherwise - I am comfortable with readr for what I'm doing so this is by far a better choice in that case

Comment: From which package is `read_csv`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

After all, I found that is related to the way the file was saved. I fixed it saving the Excel file with CSV UTF-8, delimited by commas.

After it I used the traditional

```
read.csv(file.choose(), fileEncoding ="UTF-8", header=TRUE, sep=";")
```

without any problem.