# Exported Data from Tableau into R

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have a dataset that I exported from Tableau that I am now trying to import into R.

I am getting the following error message: Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at 'D'

When I open my data in a text editor (sublime text), it looks like this:

```
Date hour minute region amount

March 29th, 2016 2 43 KY  4 
March 29th, 2016 2 58 CA  30
```

The headers are delineated by tabs.

I've tried saving it with UTF-8 encoding, but R is still not able to read it. 
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you importing it? does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv) help

Comment: Some things to try: setting the `sep` and `fileEncoding` arguments explicitly. Can you post your "read.csv" command?