# Import a file with pound symbols (£) in R

Tags: r, currency, file-import

this was expected to be much easier but I cannot get it done in R. I have a very simple file which contains some information stored as strings. There is also a currency tab, which contains characters like "$" or "£".

I use the following to import the file, wich works fine:

```
x <- read.csv("C:/file_information.csv", sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F, 
              row.names = 1, header = F)
```

The file has a structure like this (it contains also NAs):

```
matrix(c("A","B","","","£", "$","D","E","C"),3,3)
```

How can I import this file correctly? I tried to play around with the `fileEncoding` option, but could not get it done.

The csv was originally created from excel 2013 (comma delimited csv).

Surprisingly dollar signs are displayed correctly but for pound signs there is a question mark in a black square instead.

Comment: Which encoding is used for the CSV file? How have you tried to load it with the appropriate encoding?

Comment: Its the default: Westeuropean(Windows). I cannot choose this in R, can I?
Edit: I read somewhere the correct name for it is 'excel ANSI encoding',

Comment: Sure you can. You just have to know the *formal* name of the encoding (in this case, it's either ISO-8895-1, or Microsoft's superset of it, Windows-1252), and then that that encoding is called `latin1` in R. Then, your question should be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv).

Comment: Sorry my bad. It actually did fix the problem. When I print the table on the console it displays correctly. It only didn't display correctly when I clicked on the table on the right hand side of R Studio in order to generate the preview. Seems to be an issue with the file previewer then. Thank you!