# Loading data in RStudio - "invalid multibyte string 109"

Tags: r, zoo

I am attempting to load a txt-file into RStudio using zoo time series. When doing so I get the following error:

"invalid multibyte string 109",

when loading in as follows:

```
library(zoo)

funds = read.zoo("funddata.txt", header=TRUE)
```

Does anyone know why I get this particular error-code?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv?rq=1, maybe you could try `funds = read.zoo("funddata.txt", header=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: What exactly is in this input file? Are you sure it's a plain text file? Do you know the encoding? What OS are you on? Where did the file come from?

Comment: @rmagno Thank you for responding to my question! Using your code suggestion made no difference to the error-code.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for responding to my question! The input file contains mutual fund data of a 106 funds from 1983 til 2019. It is nothing suggesting that it is anything other than a plain text file. MacOS Catalina. The file is constructed from a website making fund data (professionals).

Comment: This looked to be have working:
````
funds = read.zoo("funddata.txt", header=TRUE, fileEncoding="latin1")
````
Thanks @rmagno for the link.