# Rscript prompt 'invalid mul tibyte character in parser at line 1'

Tags: r, cmd

When I run Rscript d:/s.R, it prompt:

> invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1 Execution halted

the contens of s.R is:

```
paste("到达第","天",sep="")
```

and the encoding of s.R is UTF-8.

How to solve this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv

Comment: Thanks, when run paste("到达第","天",sep="") in R environment, it is normal, but in Rscript, it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows with Chinese locale, try to open it in notepad and ‘Save as’ ANSI encoding.

ref: https://d.cosx.org/d/419609-windows-cmd-r