# How I can solve the error: make.names(col.names, unique=TRUE): invalid multibyte string 7?

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to import a csv file in r, with the code:
`read.table(file.choose(), header=T, sep=",")` and `read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)`

but I got the next error:
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) :  invalid multibyte string 7

I tried to solve this with the next code:
`Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English")`

But it gave me some unexpected output. Can somebody give me some feedback or suggestion what to do? The output says:

```
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "English") : using locale code page other than 65001 ("UTF-8") may cause problems
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid multibyte string in read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv)

Comment: Please provide an example of what you expect it to produce and what it is actually producing ("unexpected output"). The warning message is just a warning, not an error. See this for solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv

Comment: In this case, the warning message is unrelated to the error

Comment: After the read.csv or read.table with the argument file.choose() I expect a window where I can browse for the csv file, select it and when I say enter (open) it start reading/importing the file. After a couple of seconds it should give me no error, just the data in the dataset