# Invalid multibyte string importing txt file

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to import a txt file with either `read.delim` or `read.csv`:

```r
read.delim("DATASET ANALISIS ACV COMPLETO.txt", sep = "\t")
```

And it returns the following error:

```
Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<a8>?.0'
```

I have seen a similar question ([Invalid multibyte string in read.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363085/invalid-multibyte-string-in-read-csv/76203199#76203199)) but it is a little bit old and I only found answers regarding the specific file he wants to import, but I found the problem affects also the script and it won't read special characters (spanish language):
"interacci?n" instead of "interacción"

I have found that the only solution is to downgrade the R version to 4.1.3 from 4.3.0. I have tried every solution from the previous question I mentioned, but I just want to solve this in general, not every time that I want to import a file or write an script.

Comment: Don't you have a way through these functions, to add a charset parameter?

Comment: I may have, but as I say I don't want to be adding parameters every time I want to import a file that never gave me any problem until I updated R version to 4.3.0

Comment: I guess your file's encoding is not UTF-8 but that's what R expects. So either change your file's encoding or tell R which encoding you are using with the `fileEncoding` argument to `read.csv`.

Comment: I made sure my file's encoding is UTF-8 and it returned the same error. Also, why would the encoding matter in version 4.3.0 and not in 4.1.3?

Comment: I thought there might have been some changes in encoding defaults between the versions but maybe that's not the case. Can you share your input file (or a part of it with these problematic characters)?