# import CSV Files containing German Umlauts into R

Tags: r, import

I am working with R Studio and need to import a csv File for Text mining.
The File is windows-1252 encoded and contains German Umlauts.

However I cannot get R to import these Umlauts correctly. using read.table(X,fileEncoding="UTF-8") results in an error.

What am I missing?

----UPDATE----

The File I am trying to read is: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kGh2YwTmb9U3hkei1TTHlUME0/edit?usp=sharing

Using this R Code:

`Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "german")
dataset <- read.table("../processed/DE_all_CDM_201405050001_DE_all_CDM2014-05-05_rcout.csv", encoding="UTF-8", header=TRUE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=F, as.is=T)
dataset <- dataset[,c(1,11,30)]
Encoding(dataset[,2]) <- "UTF-8"`

Comment: Have you read the "Note" section in `read.table`?

Comment: Yes, but Im not sure if I understand correctly. My Locale is : "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"

And Im running windows...

Comment: Have you set the Sys.Locale?

Comment: You may want to read this. it's for russian but the same applies im sure for any foreign language http://quantifyingmemory.blogspot.ie/2013/01/r-and-foreign-characters.html

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069908/r-extracting-clean-utf-8-text-from-a-web-page-scraped-with-rcurl) useful - shows how to use the locale to import Japanese characters without them turning into line noise. Umlauts may also benefit!

Comment: Sorry, none of the obove works for me. I tried to set the locale: Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "german") which leads to i.e. "Gel<e3>ndewagen" instead of "Geländewagen". Also setting the encoding in read.table with fileEncoding="UTF-8" nor encoding="UTF-8" dont work. Encoding(df) <- "UTF-8" also has no result.

Comment: My locale is identical to what you show above (it's the default on German windows systems). In general I have no problem importing umlauts. There is something you are not showing. A reproducible example could be useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I Updated the original Post with a (hopefully) reproductible example

Comment: I won't register with Google just to download your file ...

Comment: Ok, I can see that. Do you have an alternative to upload files?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I just found out that this is a R Studio GUI issue. If I run my code in the R console it würls fine.