# 'translateCharUTF8' must be called on a CHARSXP Execution halted

Tags: r

I installed Microsoft-R-Open 3.4.0 on a Red Hat Linux Enterprise 7.3 machine following the instructions https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/installation/ .
R starts up and seems to be doing fine at first sight. However, when I try to list the files in a directory with the command

```
files <- list.files(path="/home/username/directory_name/", pattern="*.Rda",, full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
```

I get the error

```
translateCharUTF8' must be called on a CHARSXP
Execution halted
```

On my local windows machine the command works fine.
Googling this nothing really comes up except that the installation might be broken.

The strange thing is, that if I copy and paste the command into R and execute it, it does not work, but if I copy and paste it into R and change that command in a way that should not change its result but only add spaces or something like that it might run. E.g. changing it to

```
files <- list.files(path = "/home/username/directory_name/", pattern = "*.Rda",, full.names = T, recursive = FALSE)
```

might work, might not work and return the same error, or might execute but when I then type "files" that might return

```
[1]Error: 'getCharCE' must be called on a CHARSXP
```

When using R from the R-foundation (https://www.r-project.org/, installed via EPEL), I get the same error and behaviour.

The command sessionInfo() returns the following:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

uname -mrs gives me:

```
Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 x86_64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
best regards

Stefan

Comment: Do you have files with names containing accented characters? Also, note that `pattern` is supposed to be a regex, not a glob.

Comment: Does it work if you're using `pattern = glob2rx("*.Rda")`?

Comment: I mirror what Hong and hannes101 says above. Couple of more things; If you were to copy over all files etc., from your Linux box to the Windows box and ran the same command - what would the outcome be? Also, it seems that this error can happen if there is a memory corruption (in addition to "weird" characters), but as you see the error happening with both MRO as well as CRAN, I wonder if that's it. Finally: What happens if you were to reboot the Linux box, and then try again?

Comment: Additionally, I think there's one comma too many in `files <- list.files(path="/home/username/directory_name/", pattern="*.Rda",, full.names=T, recursive=FALSE` so this should be `files <- list.files(path="/home/username/directory_name/", pattern=glob2rx("*.Rda"), full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE`

Comment: Thank you very much! I indeed had files with accented characters. After renaming them such that they do not contain accented characters anymore, it works.
Using
    pattern = glob2rx("*.Rda")
still results in the error for the files with accented characters.
The second comma in the command was a copy and paste error from me, in the code I tried to execute there was no second comma.

Comment: Does simply renaming my files suffice or should I be worried that there is still something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you could also play around with the locale settings, since I suspect it concerns German umlaute, it might be helpful to change the locale settings of the R session. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245094/import-csv-files-containing-german-umlauts-into-r#24279538

Comment: Sorry for taking some time to get back to it. The answer from @HongOoi solved my problem. If you could post that as an answer I will mark it as solving my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files have names containing accented characters. Changing them to pure-ASCII names should fix the problem.

For Example

```
unicode_and_raw_filename = paste0("/tmp/\u1234", as.raw("A"))
training_rows <<- read.csv(unicode_and_raw_filename, header = FALSE)
```

produces:

```
'translateCharUTF8' must be called on a CHARSXP, but got 'raw'
```

Looks like R internals has some spaghetti code in charset conversion for Latin2, ISO_8859-2, UTF-8, and CP1252: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html