# Php - Download a Hebrew Site - Character issues

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, hebrew

Does anyone know how to download a page such as:

```
http://www.zvz.co.il/SingleAd.aspx?p=76755307&t=11&m=p
```

When I do it, I get this in the header:

```
<head id="Head1"><title> 
×–×”-×•×–×” - ×¨×›×‘: ×ž××–×“×” ×œ×× ×˜×™×¡ 323 ×ª×ª ×“×’× glx ××•×˜×•' â€1800, ×©× ×ª 1996, 8,000 â‚ª , ×ª. ×”×™×œ×•×›×™× ××•×˜×•×ž×˜×™×ª, ×™×“ ×¨××©×•× ×”, ××–×•×¨ ×™×™×©×•×‘×™× ×•×ž×•×©×‘×™× ×‘×“×¨×•× ×‘×¤×ª×— ×ª×§×•×•×”, ×ž× ×•×¢ 1,840 ×¡×ž"×§, ×ž× ×•×¢ ×‘× ×–×™×Ÿ, ×¦×‘×¢ ×›×¡×£, ×ž×¡' ×§"×ž 210,000, ×‘×¢×œ×•×ª × ×•×›×—×™×ª ×¤×¨×˜×™×ª, ×”×¢×¨×•×ª ×ž×¦×‘ ×ž×›× ×™ ×ž×¢×•×œ×” 
</title><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css" />
```

But what is truly there is:

```
<head id="Head1"><title>
    זה-וזה - רכב: מאזדה 2, שנת 2009, 80,000 ₪ , ת. הילוכים אוטומטית, יד שנייה, אזור רמת גן - גבעתיים ברמת גן, מנוע 1,400 סמ"ק, מנוע בנזין, צבע שחור, מס' ק"מ 30,000, בעלות קודמת פרטית, בעלות נוכחית פרטית, הערות שמורה ומתוחזקת.טסט לשנה(יוני 13).2 צמיגים קדמיים חדשים.בקיצור אחלה רכב עם מעט ק"מ.לרציניים בלבד., תוספות מערכת אבטחה של קוברה.מפוארת., טסט הבא 29/06/2013
</title><link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css" />
```

Do I require some special character encoding?? I using standard Php & cUrl to just do a simple web request and download.
Please help.

Comment: Post your PHP code so we can see what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similar threads that maybe of help to you:

[R: extracting "clean" UTF-8 text from a web page scraped with RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069908/r-extracting-clean-utf-8-text-from-a-web-page-scraped-with-rcurl)

[Using "cat" to write non-English characters into a .html file (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483742/using-cat-to-write-non-english-characters-into-a-html-file-in-r)

Not identical in nature but maybe of help.