# Changing the unicode of a XML file in R

Tags: r, xml, encoding

I want to perform a simple task:
I have 60,000 xml files which I want to change their encoding to utf-8.
All I want to do is to write kind of a loop that reads the xml file and then saves it immediately with the right encoding. That's it. How can I do that in R?

Comment: Do they all have the same current encoding, or do you need to read the XML declaration to determine the encoding?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested  in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481799/convert-a-file-encoding-using-r-ansi-to-utf-8) post, use `iconv`.

In general:

```
writeLines(iconv(readLines("tmp.html"), from = "ANSI_X3.4-1986", to = "UTF8"), "tmp2.html")
```

On Windows use:

```
writeLines(iconv(readLines("tmp.html"), from = "ANSI_X3.4-1986", to = "UTF8"), 
           file("tmp2.html", encoding="UTF-8"))
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17133775)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying [yoh-deadfall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593390/yoh-deadfall)  Editing my reply now!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it leaves the XML declaration unchanged, which means that a subsequent attempt to parse the file may attempt to decode it incorrectly.

Comment: [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) , the above code creates another file(tmp2.html in this example), so there are 2 options:  Either rename the file after this code runs  or use the new file.